# To show that d is a metric on $R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X=\mathbb{R^2}$. Define d by:

$$d(x,y)=max{|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|}$$

In triangle inequality part we have many cases

1. If $x= y$ then $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$ is trivially satisfied

   2.If $x\neq y$ then i have cases

2.1 $x=z$ and $y\neq z$

2.2 $x\neq z$ which furthure has two subcases which are when $y=z$ and $y\neq z$
Are there mor cases?in each case do i have to consider ordinates greater than or less than cases also. If yes then it will be a mess.I am not sure whether i am going in right direction

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier. Assume without loss of generality that $d(x,y)=|x_{1}-y_{1}|$. So \begin{align}
d(x,y)&=|x_{1}-y_{1}|\\
&\leq|x_{1}-z_{1}|+|z_{1}-y_{1}|\\
&\leq \max\{|x_{1}-z_{1}|,|x_{2}-z_{2}|\}+\max\{|z_{1}-y_{1}|,|z_{2}-y_{2}|\}\\
&=d(x,z)+d(z,y)
\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain how your ineuality in second last step came. Thanks

Comment: @Gathdi, $|x_{1}-z_{1}|\leq max\{|x_{1}-z_{1}|,|x_{2}-z_{2}|\}$. The other parcel is similarly.

Answer (score 1):

No more cases are left.

It will be a tangled cases.

Here is a simpler solution:

Since $d(x,z)+d(z,y) = max\{|x_1-z_1|,|x_2-z_2|\}+max\{|y_1-z_1|,|y_2-z_2|\} \geq max\{|x_1-z_1|+|y_1-z_1|,|x_2-z_2|+|y_2-z_2|\}  $

By triangle inequality $RHS \geq max \{|x_1-y_1|, |x_2 - y_2|\} \geq d(x,y)$

Comment: I did not understand how you got inequality in second last step Thanks

Comment: @Gathdi consider there are two packets of two numbers. If one arbitrary pick one number from a packet and the one from the other, and one add up. It will always be less than the sum of maximal numbers in these two packets. Sticking to logical and math proof, $max\{x,y\} > x$, $max\{u,v\} > u$ then $max\{x,y\} + max\{u,v\}> x +  u$ Out of symmetric $max\{x,y\} + max\{u,v\}> y+v$. Finally,  $max\{x,y\} + max\{u,v\}> max\{x+u,y+v\}$ where $x,y$ in one packet and $u,v$ in the other packet.